# how to call the start activity from one java class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Is it possible to start an `Activty` using an `Intent` in a general `java` class which `extends Activity`?

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;

 public class SubActivity extends Activity{

          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           }           
 }
```

And a general java class like the following

```
class TestClass extends Activity{

       void firstsem(){
        Intent t = new Intent(this, SubActivity.class);
        t.putExtra("sub1","chemistry");                 
        startActivity(t);
   }
}
```

Is it possible to start an Activity from an general java class? Could anybody show me how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to create a function to do that. You should try a java tutorial.

Comment: There doesn't really seem to be anything wrong with this code as long as `Subject` also is a subclass of `Activity`. Have you actually tested it?

Answer (score 14):

To start an `Activity` you need a `Context`.

The method `startActivity(Intent intent)` is inherited from the `Context` class. [As it can be seen in the Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity%28android.content.Intent%29)

Also an explicit `Intent` itself needs a `Context` in its constructor.

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

As `Activity extends Context` and you've extended Activity you can use your own class as Context.
And thus simply call

```
void method() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityName.class));
}
```

If you do not want to extend Activity you can pass the Context as an argument.

```
public static void startActivity(Context context) {
    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityName.class));
}
```

BASIC IMPLEMENTATION

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        ActivityStarter.startActivityB(this);
    }
}

public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
    }
}

public class ActivityStarter {

    public static void startActivityB(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtra("sub1","chemistry"); 
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: i am new to android , can u give me example for creating context and passing it to another activity

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer in about one or two hours when I'm back at my computer. I hope that's o.k. to you.

Comment: what about if we make the ActivityB.class call as general? let say it's stored in a variable. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

Yeah, it is possible. And extending the activity is not necessary too. Let's name our custom class as `Custom.java`
Let's assume that we need to start the `NewActivity` class when `method()` is called in our Custom class.

**STEP 1:**

As [EndZeit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21888725/5038993) pointed out, you need context of your MainActivity class in your Custom.java class to start a new activity from that point.

`Custom custom = new Custom(MainActivity.this);`

**STEP 2:**

In the custom class, make a constructor and receive the context passed:

```
Private Context context;
public Custom (Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

**STEP 3:**

Now, start the new activity:

```
public void method() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NewActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You're done :)

Answer (score 5):

Just use the following code from any Java class:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(),TargetActivity.class);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
Intent t= new Intent(testclass.this,Subject.class);
```

to:

```
Intent t= new Intent(testclass.this,subactivity.class);
```

Also, put a reference to subactivity in your Manifest file

Something like:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.app.subactivity" />
```

Comment: i changed those like that but still i am getting error.In my app i have two activity main_win.xml,subject_win.xml file and corresponding java file named mainactivity.class and subject.class. i also have third class Cse.class file in my app. now after press the button in main_win.xml ,mainactivity.class receive it and call the matchSem() method in Cse.class file. now from the matchSem() method i have to start the subject.xml activity . can i do like that

Comment: But it seems you have a class named **subactivity.java**: see this **public class SubActivity extends Activity{** It's **not a good practice** to have a Java file name which is different from the lass name!!

Answer (score 2):

> In Kotlin this is how you can do it

I am asuming that you have `context` available

```
val intent = Intent(context, YourActivity::class.java)
context.startActivity(intent)
(context as Activity).finish()
```

Answer (score 2):

Start new Activity in a single line of code.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ActivityName.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

When a class extens `Activity` then turns to Activity class. So, your both classes, `subactivity`  and `testclass`, activity class.

Yeah, you can start a activity from another class.

Follow the below tutorial link...you will get to know how to start an activity from another activity

[Android activity – from one screen to another screen](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/)