# How to separate FireStore logic into own classes

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-activity, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code

```
    public String getPoolValue() {
    final DocumentReference docRef = database.collection("pool").document("bq2a7gLnz9bpEyIyQeNz");
    docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            Pool pool = documentSnapshot.toObject(Pool.class);
            valueOfPool=String.valueOf(pool.getValue());
        }
    });

return valueOfPool;
}
```

And what happens, is it goes through this code, returns valueOfPool right away without going through the onSuccess block and then goes through a 2nd time and enters on the onSuccess block. Since I return the value of pool to an activity that activity never gets the actual value.

Comment: I reopened this question because this is not an exact duplicate of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48499310/how-to-return-a-documentsnapshot-as-a-result-of-a-method. OP is not asking how to return value. OP wants to get the value and pass it to an activity from a class that doesn't extend an activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`get()` method is asynchronous which means the return statement will get executed before the `onSuccessListener`, that's why you don't get the actual value. Therefore if you are using this value in another activity, then you can use Intent and inside the `onSuccessListener` start the new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("value", valueOfPool);
startActivity(intent);
```

`

Comment: I always have difficulty figuring out how to use Intents from base java classes. It is recommended to separate db logic out of activities but I can never really figure it out.

Comment: If you are using a java class that doesn't extend an activity then check the following implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21888385/how-to-call-the-start-activity-from-one-java-class/21888725

Comment: Huh interesting, I think that is the answer I am looking for